# Check if DataTables data is not empty or null with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to make datatable cell "email" as a active link mailto: ...

So, i made something like this:

```
{ data: 'email',
    "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
        $(nTd).html("<a href='mailto:"+oData.email+"'>"+oData.email+"</a>");
    }
}
```

This is working, but when the row does not have email, then it will print out as "mailto:null", so I need something like IF statement to check if there is data in that cell. If there is no data then the cell will be left empty.

So, i tried something like below and its not working.

```
{ data: 'email',
    "fnCreatedCell": if ($('"+oData.email+"').val() != '') { function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
         $(nTd).html("<a href='mailto:"+oData.email+"'>"+oData.email+"</a>");
    }}
},
```

How to fix that code?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `if` **inside** the function. An `if` statement cannot be a valid Object value on its own.

```
"fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
    if (oData.email) $(nTd).html("<a href='mailto:"+oData.email+"'>"+oData.email+"</a>");
}
```